# How to output the browser User-Agent String using Web-Harvest library in Java

Tags: java, webharvest

Testing some issues with an application that has been created using the [Web-Harvest library](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/) to no avail. Our network environment has a mix of proxies and other filters and I am trying to rule out a problematic User-Agent string.

I think the issue is with how the string is being specified in the application, but I don't know how to output the supplied string for debugging.

I can see the string within the IDE debugger, but I really need this to have this output for others to test on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the headers (and other information about the http processor) by querying the http object after it is executed. 
Below is an example code which saves header information into a webharvest variable

```
<config>
    <http url="${yoururl}"></http>

    <script><![CDATA[
            String keys="";
            for(int i=0;i<http.headers.length;i++) {
                keys+=(http.headers[i].key + "=" + http.headers[i].value +"\n---\n");
            }
            SetContextVar("myCookie", keys);
        ]]>
     </script>


</config>
```

the myCookie variable then returns something like:

```
Server=Apache
---
Content-Language=en-GB
---
Pragma=no-cache
---
Cache-Control=no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
---
Expires=0
---
Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
---
Date=Thu, 17 Jul 2014 14:35:41 GMT
---
Transfer-Encoding=chunked
---
Connection=keep-alive
---
Connection=Transfer-Encoding
---
Set-Cookie=Unique=%1%enc%3~~~ Domain=~~~; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 16 Jul 2016 14:35:40 GMT; HttpOnly
---
Set-Cookie=Session=%1%V2ID~~~
---
Set-Cookie=ServerPool=A; Domain=~~~
---
Set-Cookie=005db%3Bhac01a%3A10023%3B;
---
Set-Cookie=ReturnTo=%1%%2F~~~
---
```